# GetUsernameEx not working properly for LocalSytem account

Tags: windows, api, msdn

I spawned a command prompt as local system account using below command
**psexec.exe -i -s %SystemRoot%\system32\cmd.exe**

when i give whoami, i see the output as
nt authority\system

But when i call GetUserNameEx as below
if( !GetUserNameExW(NameSamCompatible, infoBuf, &bufCharCount ) )

I get the output as DOMAIN\COMPUTER$

I want to get username as SYSTEM and check what all groups it belongs to

Any idea whats going wrong above

Comment: Both usernames are valid, which you will get depends on the specific API you're using.  One method that might give you the answer you want would be to call OpenProcessToken, GetTokenInformation, and LookupAccountSID.  (It may not be the most straightforward.)

Comment: (Note that while I suppose it is legal to do so, it would be rather unusual to explicitly add SYSTEM to a group.  If you want to know the effective group membership, you should use GetTokenInformation with the TokenGroups option.)